# Trying to render a geometry with OpenGL, but can't seem to

Tags: opengl, go

I have a `Renderer` component which can render a `Scene`. Assume the scene is just a container for `Renderable` objects. A `Renderable` is composed by a `Geometry` and a `Material`. I call that a `Mesh`. When rendering the multiple renderables, that's essentially what I do, **for each renderable**:

```
var (
    vbo      uint32
    ibo      *opengl.IndexBuffer
    geometry = renderable.GetGeometry()
)

gl.BindVertexArray(r.vao)

gl.GenBuffers(1, &vbo)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, int(unsafe.Sizeof(geometry.GetVertices())*VertexSize), nil, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW)

ibo = opengl.NewIndexBuffer(geometry.GetIndices(), uint32(len(geometry.GetIndices())))
ibo.Bind()

gl.DrawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, int32(ibo.Count), gl.UNSIGNED_INT, gl.Ptr(geometry.GetIndices()))

ibo.Unbind()
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
gl.BindVertexArray(0)
```

`opengl.IndexBuffer` is my implementation of an index buffer. It simply does:

```
gl.GenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer.ID)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer.ID)
gl.BufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, int(count)*4, gl.Ptr(&data[0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

However, I can't seem to draw my geometry. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this your **actual** render function (memory leak and all) or is it code culled from multiple functions?

Comment: It's just a first version. I'm aware of the leaks and it's not necessarily one function.

Comment: This is actually important; ignore the leaks for now and show the actual code, because your index buffer unbinding *could* be what's at fault depending on the split between creation code and drawing code.